# How to get a list of Typescript modules in Chrome Developer Console?

Tags: typescript

I have an Angular 5 app that uses Typescript. How do I query for a list of modules that in the app using Chrome Developer tool bar? How do I interact with classes/objects/properties?

Comment: Augury extension may help

Comment: Tried Augury... didn't help